# Copy contructor c++ with base and derive class

Tags: c++

I have two derived classes(`Student` and `Teacher`) who inherit from base class `People`.
When I want to declare 2 variable `st`, `tc` with type pointer to `People`, but pointing to objects of `Student` and `Teacher` types to add into this linked-link:

```
class Node
{
private:
    People* data;
    Node* next;
};
```

so I write:

```
People * st = new Student(...);
People * tc = new Teacher(...);
```

Now I want to write a copy contructor to clone `st`, `tc` (like `People *st1 = st` or everything else to clone those variales without using default code) so how can I do it?
Thank you!
p/s: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a copy constructor that does the following:

```
People p(*st);
```

The type of `p` will be `People` and not `Student` though. If you want to create a `Student` then you can add a `virtual` function to `People` called `clone` as follows:

```
class People {
...

  virtual People *clone() = 0;
}
```

And then in each derived class implement it to return an instance of the derived type. This way your usage would be:

```
People *st = new Student();
People *stClone = st->clone();
```

Here the type of `stClone` is `Student` and not `People`.

Comment: example i have code like this:
'class People {
int a;
  virtual People *clone() = 0;
}
...
class Student{
...
int b;
virtual People* clone(){???};
}'
what should i return in this funtion? sry i just a newbie in c++.

Comment: I meant return new Student(*this) ;

Comment: i just did what you said, every ok like when i use default copy contructor but when i tried to delete those clone from my linked-list then debug error. what's the diffrence between those clone and my variable? is it created a very new instance of the derived class?
my linked-list: class Node
{
public:
 People* data;
 Node* next;
};
thank you for your help again.

Comment: i tried to create one clone then delete it, when i print my list again, the original one is missing it's pointer variable. class People { private: char* name; .... }. the console didnt print People::name like before.

Comment: This calls the copy constructor and creates a new instance. If you don't want to create a copy but just use the same pointer then you don't need any of this, People *st1 = st is good enough.

Comment: In your destructor you are deleting the next pointer since when you copy you shallow copied your next pointer it invalidates all copies.

Comment: i just checked memory address of 'Name' (in class People i said before). it isnt change after i copied 'st' to 'stClone' as you said so that when i delete the original, the clone is deleted too. here is my function to create name: 
 Name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
 strcpy(Name,name);
I dont know why compiler dont  allocate new address for this variable. @Benjy Kessler

Comment: Why not use std::string? If you need pointers then the way to solve this issue is to use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers.

Comment: this is an excercise. and those excercise always ask to do the hard way. T_T